# How to handle nested json with Spring Webflux and Webclient

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to consume the moviedb api with spring webclient but i dont know how to handle nested json.

these are my models:

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MovieDbResponse {
    private String page;
    private List<Movie> results;
    private String total_pages;
    private String total_results;
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Movie {
    private boolean adult;
    private String backdrop_path;
    private int[] genre_ids;
    private int id;
    private String original_language;
    private String original_title;
    private String overview;
    private float popularity;
    private String poster_path;
    private String release_date;
    private String title;
    private boolean video;
    private float vote_average;
    private int vote_count;
}
```

and this is my webclient:

```java
public class MovieDbClient {
    @Value("${moviedb.apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Autowired
    WebClient webclient;

    public Mono<MovieDbResponse> searchMovie(String movieName){
        Mono<MovieDbResponse> movieDbResponse = webclient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/search/movie")
                        .queryParam("page","1")
                        .queryParam("query",movieName)
                        .queryParam("api_key", apiKey)
                        .queryParam("include_adult","false")
                        .queryParam("language","en-US")
                        .build()
                )
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MovieDbResponse.class);
        return movieDbResponse;
    }
}
```

I have the problem that i get my page, total_page and total_results but not the results array

Comment: Please, share sample JSON response.

Comment: ```json
{
    "page": "1",
    "results": [],
    "total_pages": "0",
    "total_results": "0"
}
```